# RazorPay Android: stuck in RazorPay view when callback_url is used

Tags: android, kotlin, razorpay

I am implementing **RazorPay Android Standard SDK** for Order and Payment purposes.

Following is the code for payment:

```
private fun startPayment(razorPayId: String, paymentOrderId: String, totalPrice: String) {
    val co = Checkout()
    co.setKeyID(razorPayId)

    try {
        val options = JSONObject()
        options.put("name", "Payment")
        options.put("description", "")
        options.put("order_id", paymentOrderId)
        options.put("currency", "INR")
        options.put("amount", totalPrice)
        options.put("callback_url", "${ApiConstant.BASE_URL}orders/payment")

        val preFill = JSONObject()
        preFill.put("email", getEmail())
        preFill.put("contact", getPhoneNumber())

        options.put("prefill", preFill)

        val theme = JSONObject()
        theme.put("hide_topbar", false)

        options.put("theme", theme)
        co.open(this, options)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error in payment: " + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

I have used **callback_url** for securing my payment. The problem is when I used this in test mode, I am getting stuck on the Success page of RazorPay and I am not able to have success callback in my app.

In the given screenshot, the message `{"payment": "success"}` is the response from my **callback_url**.
If I press back on this page, I am having two options displayed in the screenshot.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so finally I got a reply from RazorPay Support that there is no such thing as callback_url for Android Standard SDK.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, thank you but how are you verifying the payment signature?

Comment: You need to user Order API and need to pass generated Order Id in checkout options. If everything went well then using PaymentResultWithDataListener method, you should get all three parameters: razorPayPaymentId, ordered, signature.

Comment: That is all correct but the docs also include the signature verification on our own backend. Here in the info-graphics from the official docs https://razorpay.com/docs/assets/images/orders_workflow.png

Comment: Yes. You can pass the data from the front end and verify it with your Secret key on the backend